# How to set @Pattern directive for graphql enums?

Tags: graphql-java

How to set @Pattern directive for graphql enums.

I didn't know how to apply constraints on ENUM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the directive and mention on ENUM, ENUM_VALUE

> directive @constraints{
>
> pattern String
>
> }on ENUM | ENUM_VALUE